# how to add data from ui (made using pyqt) to sqlite db?

Tags: sqlite, pyqt, qtsql

i have made a simple pyqt gui with QLineEdit and QPushButton. i like to add **showurl**(in con.py given below) to sqlite db.  the code :
ui.py

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Form"))
        Form.resize(400, 300)
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(Form)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout_2"))
        self.verticalLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("verticalLayout"))
        self.inserturl = QtGui.QLineEdit(Form)
        self.inserturl.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("inserturl"))
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.inserturl)
        spacerItem = QtGui.QSpacerItem(20, 40, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Minimum, QtGui.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.verticalLayout.addItem(spacerItem)
        self.insertdb_btn = QtGui.QPushButton(Form)
        self.insertdb_btn.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("insertdb_btn"))
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.insertdb_btn)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addLayout(self.verticalLayout)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form", None))
        self.insertdb_btn.setText(_translate("Form", "ok", None))
```

con.py

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui, QtSql
from insertdb2_ui import Ui_Form

def createConnection():
    db = QtSql.QSqlDatabase.addDatabase('QSQLITE')
    db.setDatabaseName('webscrap.db')
    if db.open():
        return True
    else:
        print db.lastError().text()
        return False

class Test(QtGui.QWidget, Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Test, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.insertdb_btn.clicked.connect(self.onClick)


    def onClick(self):
        showurl = self.inserturl.text()

        print showurl
if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    if not createConnection():
        sys.exit(1)
    window = Test()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

i made the input data ie. showurl print on terminal. i want to add the showurl to sqlitedb ***webscrap.db***  which has fields *id* and *url*.

I am also confused about using model view(QSqlTableModel, QDataWidgetMapper).

Comment: I'm sure the example could further be reduced until only the important part for the question remains. That would make the question more useful for others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `QtSql.QSqlQuery()` class to create query objects that interact with your database. To execute a query (in this case, an `INSERT` query), perform the following steps:

1. Instantiate a `QSqlQuery()` object.
2. Call the `prepare()` method on that object, passing to the `prepare()` method the SQL text that you want to execute.
3. Use the `addBindValue()` method to pass in variables to your query -- in this case, you want to pass in `showurl`.
4. Finally, call `exec_()` on the query object to execute
   the query. If there is an error, you can retrieve it by calling on
   the query object `lastError().text()`.

So, in code, you would need to change your `onClick()` function to:

```
def onClick(self):
    showurl = self.inserturl.text()
    query_object = QtSql.QSqlQuery()
    query_object.prepare("INSERT INTO table (url) VALUES (?)")
    query_object.addBindValue(showurl)
    if not query_object.exec_():
        print query_object.lastError().text()
```

**Please note** that I did not specify a table name to insert into because you provided field names (id and url) but not a table name; therefore the query string uses a fake table name (`table`). You should replace this with a real table name. If you do not have a table in your database, you need to create one. Please reference https://www.sqlite.org/lang.html for documentation on SQLite commands (e.g. for creating tables). Please also refer to the PyQt4 documentation on `QtSql.QSqlQuery()`: http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qsqlquery.html

For `QSqlTableModel` and `QDataWidgetMapper`, it is difficult to help without having a specific question to answer about them, but I highly recommend that you check out this excellent guide to both of those classes: http://doc.qt.digia.com/qq/qq21-datawidgetmapper.html. This guide does not use PyQt4 (instead it uses Qt alone, so the code is in C++), but the code is sparse and the concepts should resonate even if you are not familiar with C++.